# Arm template change keyvault networking settings

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to set keyvault ip restrictions in my arm template. The problem is that the IP addresses are correctly set after deploying the template, but the main setting `Allow access from` stays on `All networks`:

[image]

When I change the setting to `private endpoint and selected networks`, I see that the IP addresses set in the template are present. When I then save and refresh, the setting is set correctly.

When I then export the template and compare it to the original template, there is no difference. Is this setting missing in arm templates, or is there another way to set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, it seems I missed it. There is a `DefaultAction` option in the ARM template. For some reason it seems that the export template doesn't update that setting when changing it. When I set this option to `Deny`. It works